# Comment Count on Entry Table (SQL Query)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

It may be a simple/specific question but I really need help on that. I have two tables: `Entry` and `Comment` in a SQL Server database. I want to show **comment count** in **entry table**. And of course comment count will increase when a comment is added. Two tables are connected like this:
 `Comment.EntryId = Entry.Id`

`Entry` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entry] (
    [Id]                  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Subject]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Content]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Type]                NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [SenderId]            NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Date]                DATE           NOT NULL,
    [Department]          NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Faculty]             NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [ViewCount]           INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [SupportCount]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [CommentCount]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

`Comment` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comment] (
    [Id]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [EntryId]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [SenderId]         NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Date]             DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Content]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [SupportCount]     INT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I am showing the entries in a gridview in codebehind (c#). The question is this, what should I write as a query to do this most efficiently? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is it really necessary to store the comment count? Why not write a View that calculates it?

Comment: If seems like CommentCount should be a computed column on Entry if you truly want it to be a column in the DB at all.

Comment: I would say you need to drop these columns from this table `SupportCount` and `CommentCount`   , as they violate the 3rd normal form, i.e a column in a table should only be dependant on the primary key. a `View` should do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select e.Id,e.date,count(*) as NumComments
from Entry e
join comment c on c.entryId=e.id
group by e.id,e.date
```

If there might be no comments, try the following

```
select e.Id,e.date,count(c.entryId) as NumComments
from Entry e
left join comment c on c.entryId=e.id
group by e.id,e.date
```

Comment: thanks but i got an error like: `Column 'e.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` and i need to show the dates.

Comment: Show entry dates or comment dates?   Add e.Date to both the SELECT and the GROUP BY to solve the error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use **left join** for that purpose. Kindly me more specific with what fields you want in `gridview`

And why do you want **commentcount** in table (most tables have that **1-many relation** and we didn't use that). If you keep that in table you have to update `entry` table every time when comment is made.